# Does JVM parameter UseContainerSupport use limits or requests

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, jvm

The parameter `-XX:+UseContainerSupport` sets memory settings of the JVM according to the resources availble to the container.
In kubernetes you can define `limits` and `requests`:

```yaml
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: '${LIMITS_CPU}'
    memory: '${LIMITS_MEMORY}'
  requests:
    cpu: '${REQUESTS_CPU}'
    memory: '${REQUESTS_MEMORY}'
```

Which of the two parameters is used for the memory computation in the JVM?

Comment: `limits` is what reflected on cgroupfs and what JVM sees.